# Network Drive Permissions

Tags: mount, fstab

I want to save images from Bird-Table cam to a network drive but struggling to mount and connect.

So far I have:-

created /home/pi/TableCam

created /home/pi/TableCam/share (not sure why tho!)

edited FSTAB and added:-

//192.168.1.156/Pictures /home/pi/TableCam cifs guest 0 0

When my python runs camera.capture('/home/pi/TableCam/image.jpg') it saves in local drive but not on network drive.

However, when I SSH in and run "SUDO MOUNT /home/pi/TableCam" it successfully mounts and python works.

I'm guessing its a permission thing in FSTAB but don't understand enough about it.

Appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely clear on your question, but **it seems** that your problem **may be** in your `/etc/fstab` file. We'll try that first, and if you can give some **feedback** as we go through this, perhaps we can solve it.

Let's first try changing your `fstab` entry to this:

```
//192.168.1.156/Pictures /home/pi/TableCam cifs rw,username=xxxxxx,password=yyyyyy,nofail,vers=1.0 0 0
```

You will need to substitute **your** `username` & `password`. If you don't have a username & password for your fileserver at `192.168.1.156` you'll need to share some details with us on that: how you control access to it, is it `Samba` or `NFS`, or ...?

Assuming you're able to supply a `username` & `password` in your `fstab` entry, run this command from the terminal (or SSH):

```bsh
$ sudo mount -av
```

Hopefully, this will show something like the following:

```
/home/pi/TableCam     : successfully mounted
```

If it doesn't, you'll need to provide the additional information I mentioned above, **and** the results of this command:

```bsh
$ lsblk --fs
```

Comment: Target is RPI running Kodi on LibreELEC with a 1TB drive. Uses Samba for access.  I used the command above and added root login credentials.

ran [sudo mount -av]

error reported:-

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -av
/proc                    : already mounted
/boot                    : already mounted
/                        : ignored
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.156,unc=\\192.168.1.156\Pictures,vers=1.0,user=root,pass=********
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Comment: eeek - sorry about formatting

Comment: I'm now wondering if I need to include the Workgroup (LIBREHD) Name in the MOUNT instruction?

Comment: Working with your command line it seems to be having problems with "vers=1.0" and runs without it. I can't see what the problem with the syntax is tho. I still have the same issue. The camera.capture doesnt run on startup but does after running [sudo mount -av].

Comment: Thinking about this (which is a first!) if the mount was working successfully from fstab on boot then running [sudo mount -av] shouldn't work should it if already mounted?

Comment: So now I am thinking fstab during boot  and sudo mount in ssh are not doing the same thing. Thats as far as my thought goes though!

Comment: Okay - so if it mounted during boot is should show up in /etc/mtab - however, it only appears *after* running [sudo mount -av]. Still feels like a permission thing?

Comment: Got there! - Wait for network! Jeez that was painful. Thanks for pointers.